# Why is my Test collection not being updated?

Tags: meteor

I am autosubscribing to a collection on the client. My code is below. I expect the client to have updated information, but it never updates. This issue manifests itself in a button never being replaced by a message unless I refresh the page.

In effect the one document I have for the 'Tests' collection should have its testCount property updated to 1 on the client, but it never happens unless I refresh the page. Shouldn't it update?

**The autopublish package is not installed.**

At this point I'm convinced there is a bug in Meteor or I just don't understand something fundamental. I'm about to install a dev version of meteor.js and figure it out or just give up until maybe Meteor.js actually works. :P

My console log:

```
Tests updated!
checking test
no test
Tests updated! Object {_id: "ea9f6002-74c7-4f37-9f10-0167b3b6f65a", testCount: 0}
checking test result
test.testCount 0
```

My server log:

```
$ meteor reset;meteor
Project reset.
[[[[[ ~/Dropbox/projects/sphela-game/sphela ]]]]]

Running on: http://localhost:3000/
inserting new test
Connecting test, getting initial data.
Test added do nothing { testCount: 0, _id: 'ea9f6002-74c7-4f37-9f10-0167b3b6f65a' }
Connecting test, getting initial data.
Test added do nothing { testCount: 0, _id: 'ea9f6002-74c7-4f37-9f10-0167b3b6f65a' }
Running test.
Updating test to 1.
Test ran. { testCount: 1, _id: 'ea9f6002-74c7-4f37-9f10-0167b3b6f65a' }
Test added do nothing { testCount: 1, _id: 'ea9f6002-74c7-4f37-9f10-0167b3b6f65a' }
```

My html:

```
<head>   <title>Testing counts.</title> </head>

 <body>   {{> app}} </body>

 <template name="app">   
   {{#if testSuccess}}
     <h1>Test complete.</h1>
   {{else}}
     <button class="btn run-test">Run Test</button>
   {{/if}} 
 </template>
```

My JavaScript:

```
var Tests = new Meteor.Collection('tests');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function() {
    Session.set('testCount', 0)
    Meteor.subscribe('connect');
  });
  Template.app.testSuccess = function() {
    var test;
    console.log('checking test result');
    test = Tests.findOne();
    if (!test) {
      console.log('no test', test);
      return false;
    }
    console.log('test.testCount', test.testCount);
    return test.testCount > 0;
  };
  Template.app.events({
    'click .run-test': runTest
  });
  function runTest(event) {
    Meteor.call('runTest');
    Session.set('testCount', 1);
  }
  Meteor.autorun(function() {
    console.log('Tests updated!', Tests.findOne());
  });
  Meteor.autosubscribe(function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('test-results', Session.get('testCount'));
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function() {
    test = Tests.findOne({})
    if (!test) {
      test = {
        testCount: 0
      };
      console.log('inserting new test');
      test._id = Tests.insert(test);
    } else {
      console.log('startup reset');
      test.testCount = 0;
      Tests.update({_id:test._id}, test);
    }
  });

  Meteor.publish('connect', function() {
    var test_;
    console.log('Connecting test, getting initial data.');
    test_ = Tests.findOne({});
    this.set('tests', test_._id, test_);
    this.complete();
    this.flush();
  });

  Meteor.publish('test-results', function(test) {
    var handle;
    handle = Tests.find({testCount: test}).observe({
      changed: _.bind(function(test) {
        console.log('Test changed', test._id, test.testCount);
        this.set('tests', test._id, test);
        this.flush();
      }, this),
      added: _.bind(function(test) {
        console.log('Test added do nothing', test);
        this.flush();
      }, this)
    });
    this.complete();
    this.flush();
    this.onStop(function() {
      handle.stop();
    });
  });
  Meteor.methods({
    runTest: function() {
      var test;
      console.log('Running test.');
      test = Tests.findOne({});
      test.testCount = 1;
      console.log('Updating test to 1.');
      Tests.update({_id: test._id}, test);
      console.log('Test ran.', Tests.findOne());
    },
  });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naomi at meteor actually answered my question for me on the Google Group mailing list. The gist of my problem was two subscribe/publish returned conflicting result sets and one was ignored.

This is actually in the documenation and I missed it:

> If more than one subscription sends conflicting values for an
>   attribute (same collection name, document ID, and attribute name),
>   then the value on the client will be that from the first subscription
>   the client activated. (Even if it is not the first to send the
>   duplicated attribute.)

The answer is to not return result sets in multiple publish statements that conflict with each other. I guess avoiding sending back the same collection would aid in avoiding this.

Naomi's full answer is below[1]:

> The behavior you're seeing gets into some details of writing custom
>   publishers based on observes in Meteor.
>
> It seems to me that what you're seeing is a consequence of how
>   multiple subscriptions work.  Here's what I think is happening.
>   Initial publish, server sends down "in collection test, there's an
>   object with id ea9f6002-74c7-4f37-9f10-0167b3b6f65a where testCount is
>   0" Session variable count is 0, so we subscribe test-results where
>   testCount is 0.  Great, our local version of the database already
>   thinks that, all subscriptions agree, no change is necessary. Session
>   variable count gets updated to 1.  Autosubscribe goes and subscribes
>   to test-results were testCount is 1.  This means that now we have two
>   publishers going: 'connect' thinks
>   ea9f6002-74c7-4f37-9f10-0167b3b6f65a has a testCount of 0 (it never
>   gets updated, how could it think differently? 'test-results' gets an
>   'added' message to say ea9f6002-74c7-4f37-9f10-0167b3b6f65a has a
>   testCount of 1 (when you run a new observe, you get an 'added' message
>   for everything in it.  Later on, you get a 'changed' message when
>   things that match that cursor change) -- but it does nothing with the
>   added message.  It looks like you were expecting a 'changed' message
>   instead. The overall result here is that since we have one publisher
>   saying ea9f6002-74c7-4f37-9f10-0167b3b6f65a has a testCount of 0, and
>   no publisher saying anything else about it, the client thinks
>   ea9f6002-74c7-4f37-9f10-0167b3b6f65a has a testCount of 0.
>
> To be sure the client sees that the testCount was non-0, all the
>   publishers that assert anything about document
>   ea9f6002-74c7-4f37-9f10-0167b3b6f65a in the collection must say that
>   testCount is non-0, with the appropriate set and flush calls.  Even if
>   you sent the message that testCount was 1 in the added callback of the
>   observe, Meteor doesn't guarantee anything about what the client sees
>   when it is subscribed to two different things that conflict about the
>   value of a document.
>
> tl;dr version:  Observing a cursor gets the added callback once for
>   everything in the observed set whenever it is first run, even if the
>   items were in the database already. When you have multiple publishers
>   publishing the same keys in the same documents, the version the client
>   sees is going to be one of them, but Meteor makes no guarantees as to
>   which one if the publishers disagree. Try not to allow multiple
>   publishers to disagree about the contents of documents, it can only
>   cause confusion.

[1] https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/meteor-talk/KBhXK6a44kY

Answer (score 1):

> This issue manifests itself in a button never being replaced by a
>   message unless I refresh the page.

When running your code and clicking the button, the button is then replaced with:

**Test complete.**

And the console displays:

```
checking test result testcount.js:10
test.testCount 1
```

I noticed one error after pasting your javascript file into my IDE; a comma after the closing curly bracket for the `runTest()` method.  But it had no negative effect when running the test as far as I can see.

Comment: Did you have the autopublish package installed?

Comment: Totally forgot about it.  After removing it, I experience the same as you.